# Unhandled exception acces violation for loop in c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am trying to calculate add some values from one vector and save them in a new vector. I am doing this in a for loop. At the beginning the code worked fine, but then i started getting acces violation errors. From what i read, you would usualy get this error when trying to use an uninitialized pointer. But the pointer i am using has been unitialized. I am sorry for the sloppy code, as i am still learning. Any hint as to what may causing the error would be of great appreciation.

Below is the code:

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#include <ctime>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;


void MulCPU(int *c, const int *a, const int NDim, const int templateSize){
    for (int i = 0; i < NDim; i++){
        for (int k = 0; k < NDim; k++){
            c[i - 1 + (k - 1)*NDim] = a[i + templateSize - 1 + (k)*NDim + k*(templateSize - 1)] - a[i - 1 + (k)*NDim + k*(templateSize - 1)] - a[i + templateSize - 2 + (k - 2)*NDim] + a[i - 2 + (k - 2)*NDim];

        }
    }
}


int main()
{

    srand(time(NULL));
    int N = 500;
    int SIZE = N*N;

    int *h_b = new int[SIZE];
    int *h_e = new int[SIZE];
    int templateSize = 3;

// ...
// Code for defining h_b
// ...

    int StartTime = clock();
    MulCPU(h_e, h_b, N, templateSize);
    int StopTime = clock();

delete[] h_a, h_b, h_c, h_d, h_e;
```

I am thinking it must be the loop that somehow messes things up. Earlier i got a heap exception aswell...

Debugger gives me:
Unhandled exception at 0x011B996B in SecondTest.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0199C0A4.

Comment: What did your debugger tell you?

Comment: What did you observe debugging your code.

Comment: Sorry guys, forgot to post the actual problem: Unhandled exception at 0x011B996B in SecondTest.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0199C0A4.

Comment: That's not a debugger message. Actually debugging your code would allow you to see the offending instruction in your source code, then inspect the related variables and pinpoint the root cause of your problem.

Comment: What are `h_a`, `h_c` and `h_d`?

Comment: `i + templateSize - 1 + (k)*NDim + k*(templateSize - 1)` may become more than `NDim * NDim`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a number of problems:

```
            c[i - 1 + (k - 1)*NDim] = 
                   a[i + templateSize - 1 + (k)*NDim + k*(templateSize - 1)] -
                   a[i - 1 + (k)*NDim + k*(templateSize - 1)] -
                   a[i + templateSize - 2 + (k - 2)*NDim] + 
                   a[i - 2 + (k - 2)*NDim];
```

When `i` and `k` are both 0, you will write to c[-501].  That is not likely to end well.  (In particular you will probably overwrite the pointers that are internal to the heap, and will cause all sorts of havoc when you free the memory.)

In addition, when `i` and `k` are both `NDIM-1`, then the first index of `a` is

```
i + templateSize - 1 + (k)*NDim + k*(templateSize - 1)
```

which is:

```
NDim-1 + templateSize - 1 + (NDim-1)*NDim + (NDim-1)*(templateSize-1)
```

which is:

```
(NDim*NDim)-1 + NDim*(templateSize-1)
```

which runs well off the end of the array.

Edit: Fixed offset error.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> for (int i = 0; i < NDim; i++){
>     for (int k = 0; k < NDim; k++){
>         c[i - 1 + (k - 1)*NDim] = a[i + templateSize - 1 + (k)*NDim + k*(templateSize - 1)] - a[i - 1 + (k)*NDim + k*(templateSize - 1)] - a[i + templateSize - 2 + (k - 2)*NDim] + a[i - 2 + (k - 2)*NDim];
>     }
> }
> ```

Your `i` and `k` both start at `0`, so in the first iteration itself when `i=k=0`, you are trying to access `c[0-1+(0-1)*NDim]`, which is `c[-NDim-1]`. So basically you are doing some invalid calculation while trying to calculate the index of the element you want to access. You can correct the first error by doing:

`c[i + k*NDim] = /*your remaining expression*/`

Since I do not know what indexes you wish to achieve after that, you will need to figure out yourself. But this is the error that is bugging you.